# Inferring highest bid and lowest ask from forex trade data

Tags: fx, history

I have historical trade data for every trade on a forex exchange, whcih includes the following data:

- Time the trade was made
- Amount, in currency A
- Price, in currency B

I have also used this to organize the data into candlestick data for periods, which includes:

- Volume in currency A
- Volume in currency B
- Low price
- Open price
- Close Price
- High price
- Number of trades

---

How will I be able to use the data I have to infer the highest bid or lowest ask at a certain point in time? Also, is there any way I will be able to guess the volume of the high bid/low ask orders?

This won't be a perfect solution because I don't have access to historical market depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are trying to do is not recommended; especially in FX market.

here is why:
- The spread changes depending on time of day and trading venue.
- FX market is based on quotes. What you see is not what you get. This also depends on the broker you are using. 
- FX market changes all the time; hence the spread today; may be different than same day last year.

I suggest you gather statistics on the spread variance; and use the worst case scenario as a fix spread for all your data.

You cannot infer the volume in FX market. It also depends on time of day; and all the stuff listed above.